# Calling liferay portlet as web service with REST API

Tags: web-services, rest, liferay, portlet

I am currently moved to a new project dealing with liferay. I have been also assigned with  a new task of developing a web service using REST api in liferay portlet(i.e. to create a new plugin). I did a google search of "Calling liferay portlet as web service with REST API", I got some theory stuffs but not any sample code. I am new to this liferay stuff and my awareness regarding this is very limited. I have a very limited deadline on this.

Any pointers or sample code or tutorials on this are highly appreciable. Please help.

Comment: Liferay's built in web services APIs generate non-RESTful web services.  I posted an answer to this in your other question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18789554/difference-between-portlet-and-a-webservice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a long hours on the internet I found the answer to be very crisply written(follow the link below) with some `code samples` and apt explanations. I found this useful. When I am done with my complete code I will also post that for everyone's benefit :)

https://liferay.dev/blogs/-/blogs/integrate-jersey-restful-with-portlet-project