# Is a servlet inside a portlet required to make the portlet as a web service?

Tags: web-services, rest, servlets, portlet, liferay-6

I have few questions with respect to `portlets and servlets`. This may be a continuation of

[my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18788842/calling-liferay-portlet-as-web-service-with-rest-api).

I m trying to create a portlet which should act also as a web service. I dont know Why,

but the client requires it this way. I negotiated with the client that I can make a

separate web service application using simple jersey servlet... but cannot convince.

I have the following doubts:

1. A portlet by itself cannot represent independently to the outside world. If that is

the case then what is the benefit in making a portlet as a webservice than not making a

complete webservice project with just servlets?

2. By web searches, I came across few code sample which can make a portlet as  a

webservice. These sample codes suggested me to create a portlet, in the web.xml include the jersey-servlet and servlet container to make the **portlet as a web service**. Though it might work(I m trying hard to make a working codebase) but why to include a servlet container inside the portlet container which is already residing inside a servlet container. Sounds confusing? The following image can convey by doubt:

[image]

In this the liferay is a the servlet which is visible to the browser first. This has

multiple portlets in it. If I am making a portlet as a web service then I have to make it

visible to the browser, so I m including a servlet inside the portlet(Its my assumption

according to the [sample code from web](http://www.liferay.com/web/pradip.bhatt/blog/-/blogs/integrate-jersey-restful-with-portlet-project)). This is like taking a round trip to touch my nose.

I really dont understand why this architecture is like that. The following points which I

guess is sensible for making a portlet as web service are:

(i)  If I make a servlet(a separate project) for web service then (working as a liferay developer in the team) we cannot claim this as a liferay project.

(ii) If the web service is a portlet then I can have inter-portlet communication. In case of servlet it cannot(if I m not wrong).

Please suggest.

Comment: Did you checked with your client about whether he requires WSRP? WSRP is a way to access the portlet as a web service from remote servers. With this you can create a Portlet for your local and create a Web Service Remote Portlet for the remote Servers.

Comment: If it serves the above requirement then the client is fine... Kindly post some pointers for better understanding... In any case, I should be having some clarity for the above doubts...

Comment: Refer Liferay's wiki for WSRP. http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/WSRP

Comment: @Raghavendra Reddy Busireddy: I dont need a presentation layer... just a web service to process the request and respond by using json... Can I skip using presentation layer in WSRP portlet?

Answer (score 0):

I think this can drive you to what you need. A portlet can be called in a EXCLUSIVE mode, where no portal or portlet content are generate in the response. So you can produce whatever "HTML" or data you need as a response.
Im researching and starting with Restful, but it seams like a request/response HTML communication. The main difference is the annotation that map an HTML to a Class and methods in standard modes. In liferay you can assign an URL to your portlet. It can produce a behaviour like the one in Restful.